# Stripe Subscription Custom Yearly

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, stripe-payments

Has anyone of you tried implementing stripe subscription plan with a recurring charge not yearly but every 3 years? Here's the situation.

1. Customer subscribe to Promo Plan. Instead of having 1 year subscription they will be given a 3 years subscription for the price of 1 year.
2. After the 3 years then they will be automatically charge with 1 year subscription this time the recurring charge will be yearly.
3. So basically user will pay a amount of $1k for the first 3 years. Then on the 4th year recurring charge will kick in.

Question. Are there any option in stripe that I can do this? Like setup a plan that will deduct the user and re-charge the customer on their 4th year?
From what I see on stripe when the customer subscribe to yearly plan they will be given 1 year subscription then the next year another charge will be deducted so its a yearly deduction. What I want is for the span of 3 years deduct only once upon purchase. After the 3 years another deduction which will only last for 1 year and another deduction will take place after a year.

It's something like this

Year 1: Deduct $1k

Year 2: no deduction

Year 3: no deduction

Year 4: Deduct $1k

Year 5: Deduct $1k

Year 6: Deduct $1k

and so on...

I don't have the code since I don't know how to implement this. Hope someone can help me on this. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Card networks only support subscriptions that renew yearly as charging a customer now and then charging them three years from now is likely to surprise many customers and lead to a high risk of chargebacks.

You should charge them today, give them access for 3 years and once their access is over, provide them the option to subscribe yearly.

Comment: Guess this is the only option I can do. Thanks again